# Android: how to prevent dynamic background drawable from stretching

Tags: android, layout, view, background, stretching

I need to set the layout's background dynamically by calling myView.setBackgroundDrawable(BitmapDrawable bdb), but I want to crop the image rather than stretching it in the layout, is there a way doing it?

I was trying to create the drawable as below to set the gravity, but the challenge is I can't hardcode the android:src to a static drawable since the image source has to be dynamic.

```
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/background" android:gravity="center" />
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

Comment: You should pick an answer, it would help others who come here looking for an answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `android:gravity` attributes you are looking for are `clip_vertical` and `clip_horizontal`, but a word of advice.  These attributes may not behave the way you think they should.  You cannot use them to clip an image in both directions, only one.  The following code:

```
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="clip_vertical|clip_horizontal" />
```

does not allow the image to be cropped in both directions...it actually fits the image inside the view as if you had not set either one.  It also can be confusing that setting a clip parameter essentially sets that direction to fit the view, with the other direction being cropped out.  A few examples:

```
<!-- Force fit top/bottom, crop left/right with image centered -->
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="clip_vertical" />

<!-- Force fit top/bottom, align image left and crop right edge -->
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="left|clip_vertical" />

<!-- Force fit left/right, crop top/bottom with image centered -->
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="clip_horizontal" />

<!-- Force fit left/right, align top and crop bottom egde -->
<bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="top|clip_horizontal" />
```

Notice that these settings allow an image larger than the view to be cropped, but if the image is smaller than the view, its contents will still be stretched to fit.  In order to govern how an image will behave in a `<bitmap>` tag when it is smaller than the view, look at `tileMode`.  Note that `tileMode` and `gravity` cannot be used together; `gravity` will be ignored if both are included.

If you need more dynamic control of how the image scales in addition to this, and you do not want to use an `ImageView`, you could also wrap the resulting Drawable in a `ScaleDrawable` and configure the x/y scale percentages in Java code based on the measured view sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. myView is not an imageView though, it's a relativeLayout

Comment: Ah, in this case, you can just crop the bitmap before you turn it into a BitmapDrawable: `Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBm, 0, 0, originalBm.getWidth() - cropWidth, originalBm.getHeight() -cropHeight);`

Comment: Well, as an alternative, why don't you just add another ImageView and use that as the background instead of the actual RelativeLayout background.

Comment: that was my first approach but it didn't work either. Also I don't want to use an imageView since I want it to be a background (canvas) and there're other images that need to be displayed on top of it